# Suplantación de usuarios en Laravel

Tags: laravel, session, cookies

Tengo que hacer un sistema de suplantación de usuarios en Laravel, de modo que los administradores de la aplicación puedan acceder como un usuario no administrador, para darle asistencia técnica, o ver un supuesto problema que reporte un usuario. Lo hago llamando por post a un controlador, al que le paso el id del usuario que quiero suplantar en una variable llamada `user_id`. Dentro del controlador, hago una autenticación con id, así:

```
auth()->loginUsingId($request->user_id);
```

A continuación llamo a la vista `/home` (o la que sea, eso da igual), y se muestra la vista como la ve el usuario suplantado. Hasta ahí, todo bien.

Además, necesito que la vista del usuario suplantado se abra en una pestaña nueva. Necesito que sea así, pq hay que poder ver (y manejar) la página del administrador, teniendo abierta la del usuario. Eso no es problema, porque en el enlace que llama al controlador de suplantación incluyo `target='_blank'`, y asunto resuelto.

El problema es que el usuario suplantado no se abre con una sesión diferente, si no con la misma sesión. Así, cuando cierro la ventana del usuarios suplantado, me encuentro con que la ventana del administrador ya no es del administrador, si no que me aparece logueado el usuario suplantado. Además, si en la pestaña del usuario suplantado cierro sesión, la sesión del administrador también se cierra. Es decir. Sólo estoy manejando una sesión, de modo que lo que hago en la ventana del usuario suplantado me afecta a la sesión de administrador.

La cuestión es saber como puedo abrir una pestaña como un usuario suplantado, sin que me interfiera en la sesión de administrador que tengo en la pestaña desde la que suplanto. No sé si se puede hacer que se cree otra sesión aparte para el usuario suplantado, o debe hacerse con cookies, o cual es la solución correcta.

Comment: Entre lo que logro entender, quieres tener 2 sesiones abiertas en el mismo navegador en pestañas diferentes. Algo parecido a lo que hace Google con sus sesiones de usuario. Ahora, la cosa es que Google usa un esquema algo elaborado sobre las rutas. Si te das cuenta, un usuario tendrá una ruta con un númeto 0, y el siguiente con un número 1, y así sucesivamente. No sé si es eso lo que deseas, o tal vez yo estoy entendiendo mal. Saludos

Comment: Bueno, sí. Básicamente es eso: tener dos o más sesiones abiertas en distintas pestañas del navegador, de forma que unas no interfieran con otras. No sé como lo hace google, mis conocimientos no llegan hasta ahí, pero si conoces la forma de hacerlo con Laravel, te agradeceré que me detalles los puntos básicos lo más posible. Un saludo.

Comment: Puedes guardar en sesion el ID de usuario.
La variable de sesión te dice quien quieres ser y Auth::user() te dirá quien eres (usuario logeado). En el caso de tus clientes tiene que ser siempre igual (sesion == login), y en el caso de los administradores puede ser distinto.